# LyLuaTex padding issues

Tags: spacing, music, padding

Music in LyLuaTex output has extra horizontal padding to the left, making the music "indented" relative to the document.

```
% !TEX TS-program = LuaLaTeX

\documentclass{article}

\title{lyLua\Tex\ Problems}

\usepackage{lyluatex}

\begin{document}

\section{Inline}

There is extra space between the end of text and beginning of in-line music. I don't understand:\lilypond{\new RhythmicStaff {\time 3/4 c4( c16) c c c c c c c \bar "|."}}. I don't understand.

\section{Score}
The same is true for an engraved score. See example below:\par
\bigskip
Start slowly and then increase in ascending until you reach the forte, then decrease in descending until you reach the piano. Then repeat the scales (always in groups of three) with the colors in reverse, that is to start strong and decrease ifno to the floor in ascending, then increase to the strong in descending.

\begin{lilypond}
\header {
  title = "C Major Scale"
}

\layout {
  \context {
    \Voice
    \consists "Horizontal_bracket_engraver"
  }
}
\relative c' {

  \clef F 
  c,4-1\p\<\startGroup_\markup{gr. 3} d-2 e-3\stopGroup f-1\startGroup_\markup{gr. 4} g-2 a-3 b-4 \stopGroup
  \clef G
  c4-1\startGroup_\markup{gr. 3} d-2 e-3\stopGroup f-1\startGroup_\markup{gr. 4}
  g-2 a-3 b-4\stopGroup c-1\startGroup_\markup{gr. 3}
  d-2 e-3\stopGroup f-1\startGroup_\markup{gr. 4+1} g-2 a-3 b-4 c-5\f\!\stopGroup b-4\>\startGroup_\markup{gr. 4} a-3
  g-2 f-1\stopGroup e-3\startGroup_\markup{gr. 3} d-2 c-1\stopGroup b-4\startGroup_\markup{gr. 4} a-3 g-2 f-1\stopGroup e-3\startGroup_\markup{gr. 3} d-2 c-1\stopGroup
  \clef F b-4\startGroup_\markup{gr. 4} a-3 g-2 f-1\stopGroup e-3\startGroup_\markup{gr. 3} d-2 c-1\p\!\stopGraceMusic r
}
\end{lilypond}

Perform loudly with the right hand and softly with the left hand, then vice versa. Then switch the \textit{crescendo} and \textit{diminuendo} between the two hands.

\end{document}
```

[image: PDF Output]

What am I missing?

Comment: I have no idea what's going on here. At the moment I'm unable to get it to compile at all which was not an issue like a year ago. Since you haven't gotten any answers here have you considered asking this on the mail list? I know the lyluatex developers frequent the mail list so you might be able to catch them there.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have done that. Now we wait...

Comment: @Qohelet did you get any response so far? Same issue here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the calculation of protrusion. As a quick fix, it helped me to change line 310 of lyluatex.la like this (in fact setting any protrusion to 0):

```lua
local h_offset = indent_offset
```